# Karaf script to suspend all started camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, karaf

I would like to create a command in Karaf to suspend all Camel routes that are currently Started. Similarly, I will have another script to resume all suspended routes.

My thought was to do something like:

```
each (camel:route-list | grep Started) { camel:route-suspend $route }
```

My first problem is that `camel:route-list` does not return **values**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Camel Karaf commands cannot do this. I logged a ticket to see if we can improve this in a future Apache Camel release.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7857

So the answer is: this is not possible with the script above. You would need to write your own Camel commands and install in Karaf that can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seemed like it should be possible within the karaf scripting. I will implement a more basic script to suspend all routes.